# How to emit an event from Vue.js Functional component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

As the title of the question, `this` context is not available in the functional component. So if I have to emit an event, how can I do that?

For example in below code snippet:

```
<template functional>
    <div>
        <some-child @change="$emit('change')"></some-child>
    </div>
</template>
```

My functional component doesn't have `this` context and hence `$emit` is not available. How can I bubble-up this event?

Comment: Show your code, we cant help you without it.

Comment: @CaShiS, added the code snippet.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3348

Comment: https://alligator.io/vuejs/functional-components/ suggest rely on parent's `context.listeners`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is explained in the docs [Passing Attributes and Events to Child Elements/Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Passing-Attributes-and-Events-to-Child-Elements-Components):

> If you are using template-based functional components, you will also have to manually add attributes and listeners. Since we have access to the individual context contents, we can use `data.attrs` to pass along any HTML attributes and `listeners` (the alias for `data.on`) to pass along any event listeners.

At the most basic level, you can delegate all listeners like this:

```
<some-child v-on="listeners"></some-child>
```

If you only want to bind the `change` listener, you can do:

```
<some-child @change="listeners.change"></some-child>
```

**but** this will fail if `listeners.change` is undefined/null (not provided to the functional component).

If you need to handle the situation where there is no `change` listener, then you can do this:

```
<some-child @change="listeners.change && listeners.change($event)"></some-child>
```

otherwise you would have to settle by writing the render function by hand, since I don't think it is possible to conditionally assign the `change` listener to `<some-child>` in the template of a functional component. (Or maybe you can? I'm not sure.)

Comment: @change="listeners.change || (() => {})"

- I've never been able to get this pattern to work. Has anyone tested it successfully?

Comment: @floodlitworld This is a flaw in the vue template parser, that it can't understand that the type of this expression is a function, and can't call it properly. Instead you can do `@change="listeners.change && listeners.change($event)"`

Comment: Nina is correct, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 30):

**Child Component**

```
<template functional>
  <button @click="listeners['custom-event']('message from child')">
    Button from child
  </button>
</template>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component @custom-event="call_a_method" />
  </div>
</template>
```

[See it in action on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjvwo81py7)

> Do you want to emit the event from the vue instance?

```
export default {
  functional: true,
  render(createElement, { listeners }) {
    return createElement(
      "button",
      {
        on: {
          click: event => {
            const emit_event = listeners.event_from_child;
            emit_event("Hello World!Is this the message we excpected? :/");
          }
        }
      },
      "Pass event to parent"
    );
  }
};
```

[See it also a sandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2nm1zxv8o)

Comment: What about typescript? `listeners` var has the following signature: `[key: string]: Function | Function[];`, so you'll get an error: "This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'Function | Function[]' is callable.ts(2349)"

Comment: Can anyone point out Vue docs about the usage of `@click="listeners['custom-event']('message from child')"` like used in this example?

Comment: @Eagle_ https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass event listener conditionally you can do it inside functional component template like this:

```
v-on="listeners.change ? { change: listeners.change } : null"
```

The issue of conditionally attaching listeners is discussed [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349)

Answer (score 0):

a component with jsx:

```js
export default {
  name: "MyText",
  functional: true,// functional component
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: ""
    }
  },
  render(h, context) {
    const { props } = context;

    // with jsx

    // return (
    //   <button
    //     onClick={() => {
    //       console.log(context.listeners);
    //       context.listeners.input(Math.random().toString(36));
    //       context.listeners["my-change"](Math.random().toString(36));
    //       context.data.on.change(Math.random().toString(36));
    //     }}
    //   >
    //     {props.value}
    //   </button>
    // );

    // or use h function
    return h(
      "h1",
      {
        on: {
         // emit some event when click h1
          click: () => {
            // has value prop has has input event auto
            // event name come  what event u listen in parent component
            console.log(context.listeners);
            context.listeners.input(Math.random().toString(36));
            context.listeners["my-change"](Math.random().toString(36));
            context.data.on.change(Math.random().toString(36));
          }
        }
      },
      props.value
    );
  }
};
```

`conext.listeners` is just an alias for `context.data.on`.
in parent componet, you should listen `my-change` and `change`, or has error.

> event name inside component comes what event u listen in parent component

```html
<MyText
  v-model="value"
  @change="change"
  @my-change="myChange"
  @u-change="uChange"
/>
```

vue 2.6.11 works well.

[see the codesandbox online](https://codesandbox.io/s/emit-custom-event-functional-component-3gopr?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Parent:

```
<Child @onFunction="handleFunction">
```

and this is the child component:

Child

```
<template functional>
    <div>
        <some-child @change="execute"></some-child>
    </div>
</template>

methods:
  execute(){
   @emit("onFunction")
  }
```